# Errors while building Qt chart application using *.csv file

Tags: c++, csv, qt

While trying to build a Qt chart application for plotting a chart from a csv file, we got these errors:

[image: Errors]

Example code from: https://github.com/DarinLi/qt_charts_investigations.git

The error occurred in the following lines of `mainwindow.cpp`.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString file = ui->lineEdit->text();
    this->setCentralWidget(PlotFromCSV(file));
}
void MainWindow::on_plotButton_pressed()
{
    QString file = ui->lineEdit->text();
    this->setCentralWidget(PlotFromCSV(file));
}
void MainWindow::on_plotButton_clicked()
{
    QString file = ui->lineEdit->text();
    this->setCentralWidget(PlotFromCSV(file));
}
```

I tried to build the example files from github as it is, But the build process got failed.

Unmodified `mainwindow.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>820</width>
    <height>565</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>820</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>820</width>
     <height>565</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>510</y>
      <width>691</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="plotButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>720</x>
      <y>520</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Plot</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>720</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zugfe.png)

Comment: 1) Your example is no QML code...you are using QWidgets. 2) At a first glance your lineEdit is under the centralWidget. So you should write ui->centralWidget->lineEdit->text().

Comment: Why is the build process failing?

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but got error while compiling as shown:       qt_plotfromcsv/mainwindow.cpp:24: error: ‘class QWidget’ has no member named ‘lineEdit’
     QString file = ui->centralWidget->lineEdit->text();
                                    

/qt_plotfromcsv/mainwindow.cpp:-1: In member function ‘void MainWindow::on_plotButton_pressed()’:

Comment: Do you have a file called "ui_mainwindow.h"? It gets created from the mocking process of QT.

Comment: You are aware this repository is beginner experiments. Source code is organized in flat manner and user specific and intermediate build process files and has been check in into repository (`*.pro.user*` `*.o`). You should not use this as source of knowledge, since you will add someone else mistakes to your own.

Comment: Also error you are provided in comment do not match code you paste in question or in linked repository. You should provide a code which leads to this error. Edit: I see that Jurgen has mislead you with that.